# Get a specific string from a text file in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I looked for a long time and didn't find the exact answer to my question.
I'm kinda new to batch so maybe I didn't understand but here's my problem:

I use a batch file to do a sql query toward a remote oracle database with:

```
@echo @ScriptToExecute.sql | sqlplus username/password@database > result.txt
```

The answer is written into result.txt, it looks like this:

```
-- assumed empty --
SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production on Je Avr 27 12:34:34 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation. All rights reserved.


Connecté à :
Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production
JServer Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production

SQL>
  COUNT(*)
----------
        13

SQL>Déconnecté de Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production
JServer Release 9.2.0.6.0 - Production
```

What I want is to open this text file and get into a variable the number 13.
The purpose of this is of course to execute the batch file once every day to make sure the answer is still 13. 
In the end my batch file must return the number of the answer to my query.

The answer I want is in the line number 14.

Any thoughts ?

Thank you for your reply

edit: I tried a lot of things like using a powershell command to use head and tail command I used to know in shell but I failed to use powershell.
I also tried to use sqlcmd which can filter the results but it has to be installed and I can't install anything on the different hosts.
I tried using the command `more +13` this way:

```
@echo @ScriptToExecute.sql | sqlplus username/password@database > more +13 result.txt
```

But it didn't work either...

Comment: First thing I'd recommend you is to reduce the answer, I know there is something in Oracle configuration like `set heading off` and `set feedback off` (or similar), this will heavily reduce the SQL result and will make it easier for you to parse. In top of that, you can add something like "RESULT=" to your SQL query. When you do a `findstr` (or a `grep`) on `RESULT=` it might become far more easy to parse the SQL result.

Comment: Might this help, `FINDSTR/RXC:"[ ][ ]*[0-9]*" result.txt`?

Comment: I will try reduce it @Dominique but I'm afraid it won't work until I find a way to select a precise line in the text file :/

Comment: My code was to read the result.txt file; it should be on a new line underneath your stated working command line!

Comment: @Compo I tried every way with your code, it doesn't seems to recognise it. I tried to put it in another text file or in a variable or just to print it on the screen but nothing worked :/

Comment: Your use of `more +13` is wrong. It should be: `@echo @ScriptToExecute.sql | sqlplus username/password@database | more +13 > result.txt` After that, read just _the first line_ of `result.txt` this way: `set /P "number=" < result.txt`

Comment: Possibly `FindStr` isn't working because your `result.txt` file is being output using Unix _(LF)_ as opposed to Windows _(CRLF)_. Is that the case?

Comment: @Compo , I'm not very sure how to verify this but since I'm using windows server 2012, I tend to think it's using CRLF.

Comment: @Aacini, great !! It worked ! But my variable has the entire sentence and I would very like to get only the number and not all the blank before :/

Comment: @Compo the error message is "specified access path not found"

Comment: My command, as does Aacini's, works only on your already created result.txt. Your message is from the process creating the txt file not from the findstr command. If you look at the text I reproduced in your question, I have ran my command on that text in a file and it outputs the line containing `13`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created the file `result.txt`

```
set "numreturned="
for /f %%a in (result.txt) do if "%%a"=="----------" (
 set "numreturned=%%a"
 ) else if defined numreturned set /a numreturned=%%a&goto foundit
:foundit
echo number returned=%numreturned%
```

OR, if you don't want to create `result.txt`,

```
set "numreturned="
for /f %%a in (
 'echo ScriptToExecute.sql ^| sqlplus username/password@database'
) do if "%%a"=="----------" (
 set "numreturned=%%a"
 ) else if defined numreturned set /a numreturned=%%a&goto foundit
:foundit
echo number returned=%numreturned%
```

Note that execution directly from the prompt and as lines with a batch file are different. The `metavariable` (loop-control variable) `%%x` must be referenced as `%%x` for a batch line and `%x` if executed from the command prompt. Since it makes little sense to repeatedly execute a line containing a `for` from the prompt (it's easier to create a batch file), I post the batch-file version. User's responsibility to adjust for direct-from-prompt if desired.

Having set `numreturned` to *nothing* (ie not defined)

Read the file to `%%a`, selecting just the first token using spaces as a delimiter (default for tokens and delims)

When the first line of `-` appears (there are 10 `-` characters), set `numreturned` to some value so that it is defined.

When the next line arrives, it will not be a line of `-`, but `numreturned` is now defined, so assign the data from *that* line (the count) and terminate the loop by going to the label `:foundit`

Then analyse the value found and do whatever.

Comment: I really thought that would work but... It didn't. It seems that it only reads the first string of each line. So it read `SQL*Plus:` then `Copyright` and so on. And unfortunately on the line we are interested in, there is blank before the number we want so... It  never reach the number :/ You have any idea how to correct this ? Here is the code i got: https://ibb.co/b7WqWQ

Comment: But thanks @Magoo I'm still a little closer to the answer

Comment: The default delimiters for `for/f` include space, and leading delimiters should be ignored. You could try adding `"delims= "` but it should have no effect. The conclusion I have to draw is that the characters on that line are not spaces - which is why a cut-and-paste of the source data is preferred. If you cut-and-paste the string before the number into a `delims` clause, that should cure the problem if that character string is unaccountably not spaces.

Answer (score 0):

So, using a little of what everyone told me, here is the answer:

```
@echo @ScriptToExecute.sql | sqlplus username/password@database | more 
+13 > result.txt
set /p "number=" < result.txt
set number=%number: =%
set /A newnumber=%number
echo %newnumber%:ok
```

So I first connect to the database and create result.txt with the answer in the first line.
Then I put this first line in the variable number.
I get rid of all the blank space before my number.
Finally I create a numeric value in which I put my string and I print it.

Thank you all for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new comments, this method should work:

```
@echo off

echo @ScriptToExecute.sql | sqlplus username/password@database | more +13 > result.txt
for /F %%a in (result.txt) do set "number=%%a" & goto continue
:continue
echo %number%:ok
```

You may also try this way, that don't create any additional file:

```
@echo off

for /F "skip=13" %%a in ('echo @ScriptToExecute.sql ^| sqlplus username/password@database') do (
   set "number=%%a" & goto continue
)
:continue
echo %number%:ok
```